# JNI: native method that spawns threads that need to interact with Java

Tags: java, java-native-interface, jnienv

I have a C method that is called from a Java process:

```
extern "C" {
    JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_bla_bla_bla(JNIEnv *env, jclass java_class, jint param) {
         /* Spawn C threads that are going to call Java methods */
    }
}
```

The problem is that all what my native method gets from Java is a `JNIEnv` instance. In order to call `AttachCurrentThread()`, I need a `JavaVM` object.

How can I get the `JavaVM` pointer from my native method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One alternative is to cache the `JavaVM*` you receive in `JNI_OnLoad`.

Another alternative is to call the `GetJavaVM` function that is part of the `JNIEnv`:

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_bla_bla_bla(JNIEnv *env, jclass java_class, jint param) {
    JavaVM *jvm;
    if (env->GetJavaVM(&jvm)) {
        // Something went wrong
    }
    // Pass jvm to the new thread
```